# CAST a calculation from dates into INT

Tags: google-bigquery, casting

I am learning BigQuery, and to practice I wanted to subtract a date from CURRENT_DATE (to calculate how many days since a last log in), but the result appears as a date.

I tried to CAST and SAFE_CAST but it gives me error.

```
# Gives calculaiton result as a date

    SELECT 
            short_name,
            CURRENT_DATE-last_log_in AS days_wo_log_in,
    FROM `noted-wares-328320.demo.test_date`;

# Error invalid cast from INTERVAL to INT64

    SELECT
            short_name,
            CAST (CURRENT_DATE-last_log_in as INT) AS days_wo_log_in,
    FROM `noted-wares-328320.demo.test_date`;
```

[Table that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIEUg.png)

Is there a way I am missing?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Use [DATE_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff):

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), last_log_in, DAY) AS days_wo_log_in
FROM `noted-wares-328320.demo.test_date`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
SELECT 
  short_name,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE-last_log_in) AS days_wo_log_in
FROM `noted-wares-328320.demo.test_date`
```

with output

[image]